# How to refer correctly to a workbook from a cell that contains a volatile function?

Tags: function, excel, vba

I have a pretty stupid problem with Excel VBA. I'm trying to achieve a function that returns a workbook property of the workbook that contains the cell the function is inserted. I ran into a problem whilst making the function volatile and placing it in to personal workbook so it could be used with any of the workbooks open (also as an addin). My function is basically this -

```
Function zSETSERVERMETADATA(ByVal metaTypeName As String, Optional ByVal newValue As String = "") As String
'Recalculate upon every time any cell changes
Application.Volatile

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

On Error GoTo NoSuchProperty

'If value defined on newValue, set the value and showoutput
If newValue <> "" Then
    wb.ContentTypeProperties(metaTypeName).Value = newValue
    zSETSERVERMETADATA = wb.ContentTypeProperties(metaTypeName).Value
    Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Function
'If no value defined on newValue only show output but leave content type unchanged
Else
    zSETSERVERMETADATA = wb.ContentTypeProperties(metaTypeName).Value
    Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Function
End If

NoSuchProperty:
zSETSERVERMETADATA = CVErr(xlErrValue)
Set wb = Nothing
End Function
```

Now the problem lies in the line *Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook*, and the problem is if I have two or more workbooks open and activate the other one, the volatile function will be calculated with the value of the "new" active workbook. But this is not of course the way we want it to behave. 
I would need a bit help on this to make it explicitly always refer to the workbook where the function is calculated and not to calculate it based on the on the activity of the workbook (the workbook where the cell that has the function). Any ideas?

## Edit and the solution thanks to Gary's Student

```
Function zSETSERVERMETADATA(ByVal metaTypeName As String, Optional ByVal newValue As String = "") As String
'Recalculate upon every time any cell changes
Application.Volatile

'Set wb pointer trough caller parents
Dim wb As Workbook, r As Range, ws As Worksheet
Set r = Application.Caller
Set ws = r.Parent
Set wb = ws.Parent

'Clear unused elements
Set r = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

On Error GoTo NoSuchProperty

'If value defined on newValue, set the value and showoutput
If newValue <> "" Then
    wb.ContentTypeProperties(metaTypeName).Value = newValue
zSETSERVERMETADATA = wb.ContentTypeProperties(metaTypeName).Value
Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Function
'If no value defined on newValue only show output but leave content type unchanged
Else
    zSETSERVERMETADATA = wb.ContentTypeProperties(metaTypeName).Value
    Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Function
End If

NoSuchProperty:
zSETSERVERMETADATA = CVErr(xlErrValue)
Set wb = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to ask the Caller:

```
Public Function lin()
    Dim r As Range, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Set r = Application.Caller
    Set ws = r.Parent
    Set wb = ws.Parent
    lin = wb.Name
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the perfect solution. Hadn't even thought to use caller & parents, but works like magic!

Answer (score 0):

you can paste the wanted workbook as optional argument in your function calling

```
Function zSETSERVERMETADATA(ByVal metaTypeName As String, Optional ByVal newValue As String = "", Optional byval Wb as workbook) As String
```

Comment: Not bad option for some other case, but this would require always to pass the workbook name and for the end user might be too hard to solve what parameter this requires. Also as mentioned in the question, function needs to be evaluated explicitly based on the cell the function is in. Still thanks for the answer.